# Example of setting webpack public path at runtime

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am struggling to find an example of how to set the public path of an output file of a webpack bundle.

The [documentation](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/Configuration) says:

> If you don't know the publicPath while compiling, you can omit it and
>   set `__webpack_public_path__` on your entry point.

Like so:

```
__webpack_public_path__ = myRuntimePublicPath
```

Would anyone be kind enough to create a JSFiddle example how this can be done?

Comment: This is exactly how you do it. Make sure this is one of the first statements to run in your application.

Comment: For example in the index.html?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nothing has changed after almost two years. It's still surprisingly difficult to find an example of setting public path for webpack at runtime.

**Prerequisites**

- webpack 4.5.0
- an app big enough to leverage code splitting

For simplicity let's say our html lives in `index.html` and app entry point is `app.js`

**An example that works**

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        window.resourceBasePath = '/path/to/scripts/on/server/';
    </script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="/path/to/scripts/on/server/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
// it is important to set global var before any imports
__webpack_public_path__ = window.resourceBasePath;

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {store, history} from './store';

const render = () => {
    import('./root').then((module) => {
        const Root = module.default;

        ReactDOM.render(
            <Root
                store={store}
                history={history}
            />,
            document.getElementById('app'),
        );
    });
};

render();

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./root', render);
}
```

**An example that doesn't work**

[Webpack publicPath documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/#on-the-fly) says it's enough just to set a global variable with the right name. I did that:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        __webpack_public_path__ = '/path/to/scripts/on/server/';
    </script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="/path/to/scripts/on/server/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {store, history} from './store';

const render = () => {
    import('./root').then((module) => {
        const Root = module.default;

        ReactDOM.render(
            <Root
                store={store}
                history={history}
            />,
            document.getElementById('app'),
        );
    });
};

render();

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./root', render);
}
```

In this case my app fails complaining in console it couldn't load `0.js` from current path to `index.html`. Which means that setting public path didn't have any impact.

Comment: the first example doesn't work for me.
https://codepen.io/Ni55aN/pen/QOPKVM

I have tried `__webpack_public_path__ = ..` in <head>,
Even
`__webpack_public_path__ = window.resourceBasePath;` not works

Comment: Do you know a way to rename the `__webpack_public_path__ ` to something else to not collide with other components that using Webpack on the page?

Comment: This worked for me, al I needed to do was `window.resourceBasePath = "dynamic/path/here/";
  __webpack_public_path__ = window.resourceBasePath;`
in the app.js